# Socket.Bind Failure Troubleshooting: socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: c#, sockets, asp.net-core, .net-core

Near the end of last week I discovered that I can no longer bind to a sockets ports in most cases. This occurs in .NET Core 2.2, ASP.NET Core, and for WCF services.

I created the sample .NET Core 2.2 application below for testing:

```
  public class Program
  {
    static int Main()
    {
      try
      {
        const int connectionQueueSize = 1;
        var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(new byte[]{127,0,0,1}),5000);
        using (var socket = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        {
          try
          {
            socket.Bind(endPoint);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            Console.Error.WriteLine($"Failed to bind: {ex.Message}");
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            return 1;
          }

          try
          {
            socket.Listen(connectionQueueSize);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            Console.Error.WriteLine($"Failed to listen: {ex.Message}");
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            return 2;
          }
          Console.WriteLine($"SUCCESS: bound and listened to: {endPoint.Address}:{endPoint.Port}");
          socket.Close();
          return 0;
        }
      }
      catch (SocketException ex)
      {
        Console.Error.WriteLine($"FAILED: {ex.Message}");
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        return 3;
      }
    }
  }
```

The output of the above application is the following (both run under my account, a domain account with local admin privileges, and when run as an administrator):

```
Failed to bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at SocketBind.Program.Main() in c:\source\samples\SocketBind\SocketBind\SocketBind\Program.cs:line 19
```

**Background**:

My machine is running in an enterprise environment with more than a few pieces of security software running in addition to some antivirus software. Prior to last week, I had no problems.

Attempted solutions:

1. I ran [perfmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/perfmon) while attempting to bind, but saw nothing of interest.
2. I also ran [perfview](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview) against the ASP.NET Core application and found the exact same error occurred for both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. The output I found of interest was:

   > thisOrContextObject="Socket#15842089" memberName="DoBind" message="System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"

   The referenced socket was the IPv4 socket, but the same error occurred for IPv6 as well.
3. Per the [debugging CoreFX on Windows docs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/debugging/windows-instructions.md), I also tried grabbing a trace using logman, but I still didn't see a cause to the error.
4. I whitelisted my application both by port and by physical path in the Firewall, but neither resulted in any change.
5. Per `Get-NetTCPConnection |? { $_.LocalPort -eq 5000}`, nothing is running on the port in question.
6. Confirmed that no errors or warnings show up in the Event logs.

What can I do to identify the **cause** of the access denied error even though I may not have access to control every aspect of what's on the computer (e.g., AV/Security Software)?

Comment: Any chance of accessing the AV / Sec. softw. / Windows logs? Might be the quickest way

Comment: @C.Gonzalez, I did check the Windows logs but they didn't reveal anything helpful.

Comment: I arranged permission to have the security software temporarily disabled and was able to prove that it was the cause. That said, my question above stands. I would like to know how I could track down the cause without needing to get others involved. For example, could I use `xperf` to grab a full unmanaged/managed stack trace and then use `windbg` to identify a kernel driver (like our security software) as the culprit.